# Can't run the React Native Project using "npx react-native run-android"

Tags: react-native

I want to run the existing React Native project of my client. I tried this command already; **npx react-native run-android** and already did **npm install**. I tried to solve all the errors but still can't run the project. Here's the error output.

BUILD FAILED in 3m 23s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
at runOnAllDevices (D:\Projects\Mobile Projects\React Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (D:\Projects\Mobile Projects\React Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at D:\Projects\Mobile Projects\React Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\Projects\Mobile Projects\React Native\catholicconnect\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

Comment: At this point, literally everything can be an issue. Have you tried to do same thing with yarn installed?

Comment: Please share picture of full error screen

Comment: please share your full error

Comment: Can u share your full error?